# Shutter frozen after launch

Tags: 18.04, shutter

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME Shell 3.28.3 on XOrg
Yesterday I switched to 'Ubuntu' at login, which I understand is Wayland and today Shutter (screenshot) would launch but was frozen, but consuming 12% CPU non-stop.

I switched back XOrg but having the same problem.

Shutter can launch, it even updated plugins, but not a signle part of the Shutter UI is responding to clicks.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Oops. Found a solution soon after posting. I moved all the files out of where Shutter was storing captures to (47 images) and Shutter is functioning again.

Comment: Can you explain the location of the files please.

Comment: Worked for me as well. My location was /Pictures, but I am not sure if it is the default one or I changed it at some point.

Comment: @crafter sorry for ver late reply. Picture location is in preferences: Edit > Preferences > Main (tab) - the Directory field is where you set the picture location.